# How to create internal links during user navigation

Tags: navigation

I would like to allow users to create links between pages within the website. This wouldn't even be a problem if I asked them to edit the page, but I would like to avoid the editing step in order to make their navigation more fluid.

What I have in mind more specifically is an empty field (like a search box) on each relevant page in which the user could just copy-paste an internal URL, which would then be processed by the system to create the link between the two pages.

I have no problem seeing how I could do that once the information is entered, but I have no idea of how I could do to integrate an empty field in my page and use it in the way I described.

Any hint? Thanks! :)

Igor

Answer (score 0):

[Relations module](https://drupal.org/project/relation) was built exactly for use cases like this. But be warned that it has a little steep learning curve.

[Relations Add Module](https://drupal.org/project/relation_add) can significantly reduce your work and also has an auto-complete feature that is user friendly.

> This module provides a field that can be used to create/delete/update
>   the relations from within the node/entity forms, with a generic
>   autocomplete for each endpoint, and relation fields.

Comment: Sounds great Gokul, I'm going to delve into that... Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: The Relation Add module is perfect, precisely what I needed and it works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: It all works perfectly but I just want the blank box to display and unfortunately I can't find any way to hide the fields "Create a relation from" and "Relation type". I can't because they are not considered as fields in the module configuration. Any idea of how I could hide these fields? Thanks a lot!